# Display data using ajax when two fields are selected Liferay

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, liferay, liferay-6

I am using ajax for displaying data. When I select a name from the drop box I use ajax and data of the selected name is displayed. I use the follwing script for this:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#absentEmployeeName').change(function(){ 

        alert($(this).val());

        var absentEmployeeName = ($(this).val()); 
        alert("hi");

    if ($(this).val() != '') { 

    $.ajax({ 
        url : '${sendEmpNameResourceURL}', 
        data : { 

                <portlet:namespace />absentEmployeeName : $(this).val() 
        }, 
    type: 'POST', 
    dataType : "json", 
        success : function(jsonArray) { 

            alert(jsonArray);

            $('#myUniqueLabelId').html( jsonArray[0]+ jsonArray[1] + jsonArray[2]);             
        } 
        }); 
    } 
});
  });
</script>
```

Where  **absentEmployeeName** is the id of the dropbox where I select the name whose information is displayed using ajax.

What I want to do now is besides selecting the name from dropbox , I also want to select date; and based on date and name(from the dropbox) selected I want to display the data.
 How should I pass both the ids(of dropbox and date) to the serveresource function so that I can display the data?

In the above script:

```
$('#absentEmployeeName').change(function()
```

I am passing id of only dropbox. How to pass ids of two fields?

EDIT:

hERE IS THE SNIPPET OF MY HTML:

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('#absentEmployeeName').change(function(){ 

    alert($(this).val());

    var absentEmployeeName = ($(this).val()); 
    alert("hi");

if ($(this).val() != '') { 

$.ajax({ 
    url : '${sendEmpNameResourceURL}', 
    data : { 

            <portlet:namespace />absentEmployeeName : $(this).val() 
    }, 
type: 'POST', 
dataType : "json", 
    success : function(jsonArray) { 

        alert(jsonArray);

        $('#myUniqueLabelId').html( jsonArray[0]+ jsonArray[1] + jsonArray[2]);             
    } 
    }); 
} 
});
});
</script>

<body>

 <select id="absentEmployeeName" name="absentEmployeeName" >
 <%List<Employee> EmpList = EmployeeLocalServiceUtil.getEmployees(-1,-1);
        List<LeaveCard> leaveBalList = LeaveCardLocalServiceUtil.getLeaveCards(-1,-1);
    for(Employee emp : EmpList ) {
        long empId = emp.getEmpId();
  %>
  <option value='<%=emp.getEmpId() %>' name = "leaveEmp"><%=emp.getEmpFname()%>        <%=emp.getEmpLname()%></option>

    <%}  %>
  </select>

  <div id = "empDetails">

  </div>
  <input type = "date" id = currentDate/>

 <td colspan=2>
  <input type="radio" name="forcedabsent" value="LWP">To be treated as LWP&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="radio" name="forcedabsent" id = "absenteeEmp"> <label id="myUniqueLabelId"></label> to apply for leave<br><br>
 <b>Other instructions to Employee/HR</b><br>
 <textarea cols=60 rows=3 name = "markAbsentRemarks" id = "markAbsentRemarks">   </textarea>
 </td>

 </body>
```

Comment: can you provide your html?

Comment: @JSWorld:
Yup.. I will update it in the question.. Gimi few minutes.

Comment: @JSWorld:
I have updated the question.

Comment: Like this ==>>`data : { 

            <portlet:namespace />absentEmployeeName : $(this).val() ,<portlet:namespace />date: $("#currentDate").val() 
    } `

Comment: @Pankaj Kathiriya:
Ok Prakash so the foloowing line remains the same? no change to that?
$('#absentEmployeeName').change(function(){

Comment: @Pankaj Kathiriya:

No it is not passing the currentDate to the serveresource method.
I have fetched the data as given below on the serveresource but it is not passing the value of currentDate.

else if (typeData.equals("absentEmployeeName")) {
  
  String LabsentEmployeeName = ParamUtil.getString(request, "absentEmployeeName");
  String currentDate = ParamUtil.getString(request, "currentDate");
  
  System.out.println("the values gatheres are: " + LabsentEmployeeName + " and " + currentDate);

Comment: if you want to show data on basis of change in Employee dropdown list then yes, But if you want to show data on basis of change in any of two employeename and date, then you have to write same ajax call for on date change event. Also you have validate values of both the fields.

Comment: @SeeyaK Make sure you are getting same request parameter name what you have sent.

Comment: @Pankaj Kathiriya:
I want to display the data based on both employeeName and the date.. when both are clicked the data must be displayed..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31371/discussion-between-seeya-k-and-pankaj-kathiriya)